# What is the mistake in my code?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, symbian

The sample code mentioned below is not compiling. Why?

```
#include "QprogressBar.h"

#include <QtGui>
#include <QApplication>
#include<qprogressbar.h>
#include <qobject.h>

lass myTimer: public QTimer
{

public:
    myTimer(QWidget *parent=0):QTimer(parent)
{}

public slots:
void recivetime();
};
void myTimer::recivetime()
    {

    }

class Progressbar: public QProgressDialog
    {
public:
    Progressbar(QWidget *parent=0):QProgressDialog(parent)
            {

            }


    };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);


 QObject::connect(QTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),QTimer,SLOT(recivetime()));


 return a.exec();

}
```

It is giving me a problem when it tries to connect. I think that maybe it is fine to write the connect code in the main function.

Comment: Can you at least tell us the error? Also, you have `lass` instead of `class`

Comment: Can we see the compiler output?

Comment: This family of question was discussed at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions . Although the discussion there was at least for semantic problems, not syntactic/typing ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sum-up the previous comments and answers:

- the compiler tells you at least what it does not understand if not straight-up what's wrong with your code => if you don't understand what the compiler says post the error message with your question so that it helps those who speak "compilese"
- "connect" will connect a object's signal with another object's slot -> pass objects to connect, not classes
- the connected objects must exist for the intended duration of your connection you are connecting now at best automatic instances of QTimer which will be out of scope by the time the connect call ends.

The correct way of doing this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);

        myTimer myTimerObject(a);

        QObject::connect(&myTimerObject, SIGNAL(timeout()), &myTimerObject, SLOT(recivetime()));

        return a.exec();

    }
```

As a side note this has nothing to do with Symbian, nor is it specific to Qt 4.x. Also Qt is not QT just as QT is not Qt ;)

Answer (score 4):

Where is your `QTimer`? I think that's the problem. I haven't done Qt for a while, but as far as I remember, the first and third arguments of `connect` are pointers to objects, and you don't have a `QTimer` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Skilldrick is right !
See the qt doc [on signals and slots](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/signalsandslots.html).
The connect method needs a pointer or reference of the sender and receiver object !
But in your code :

```
QObject::connect(QTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),QTimer,SLOT(recivetime()));
```

QTimer is a class name and not a object of this class !
I mean, you need to create an object. For example :

```
QTimer* pTimer = new QTimer(a);   // QTimer object   
myTimer* pReciever = new myTimer(a);  // Your custom QTimer object with progress bar 
QObject::connect(pTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()), pReciever,SLOT(recivetime()));   
...
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but try:

```
QObject::connect(myTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(recivetime()));
```

Oops, thought myTimer was an instance of QTimer rather than a subclass. Make an instance of QTimer and give that as the first parameter. And `this` as the third.

Comment: There is no `this` in main, lest I'm misunderstanding.